# Can the java netty framework support NIO even if its clients are using thread blocking sockets?

Tags: java, c++, objective-c, sockets, netty

I'm currently developing something using netty without any changes made to it. I got the program running on java using netty for the client, however I want to do this in objective-c. The only thing i can think is to use thread-blocking sockets. However, i am unsure as to whether or not my use of thread-blocking sockets for the client will disrupt the Non Thread Blocking server

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

"Without any changes made to it" - is "it" referring to netty?  I would hope not - you have no reason to change it at all.

Netty and nio means that Netty can return to the client quickly.  Your blocking clients will only block as long as it takes Netty to respond.  Your poor design choice for clients will have no effect on Netty.